# counters, newcount and pgfcalendar, macros

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, counters, calendar

I am trying to use the `pdfcalendar` library, but I think I'm confused by the definitions.

**My Question:** What kind of LaTeX counter/macro/variable can I use with `pgfcalendar` functions?  Do I have to learn the TeX syntax?  If so, will later issues arise when these TeX counters interact with LaTeX commands expecting LaTeX-style variables?

**Background**
The TikZ manual specifies this function:

`\pgfcalendardatetojulian{<date>}{<counter>}`

and later, where the manual warns that the second argument `must be a TeX counter`, there is this function:

`\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{<Julian day>}{<week day counter>}`

How do I define `<counter>` and `<week day counter>`?

Can I use `\newcounter{mycount}` or `\newcommand{\mycount}`?

I've tried all combinations I can think of, and only got partial success.

Some [googling](https://www.texdev.net/2009/11/17/tex-counts-and-latex-counters/) led me to differences between `TeX` and `LateX` counters, but concludes that apart from syntactical variance, either was reasonably acceptable.  But it seems that `TikZ/pgfcalendar` is wanting something quite specific.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfcalendar}
\begin{document} 
\newcommand{\myisodate}{2018-06-02}
\newcommand{\myjuliandatecommand}{}
\newcounter{myjuliandatecounter}
\newcounter{myweekdaycounter}
\newcommand{\myweekdaycommand}{}
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\myisodate}{\myjuliandatecommand} %works, but prints the value, something I want to avoid.
% \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\myisodate}{myjuliandatecounter} %doesn't parse correctly
% \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\myjuliandatecommand}{myweekdaycounter} %doesn't work
% \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\myjuliandatecommand}{\myweekdaycommand} %doesn't work
\end{document}
```

Comment: `pgfcalendar`, or the whole [tag:pgf], is designed for both TeX and LaTeX. In this case you **must** use `\newcount\mylovelycounter` to declare a TeX-counter.

Comment: Basically, a LaTeX counter named `name` creates a TeX count named `\c@name`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Symbol 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433278/counters-newcount-and-pgfcalendar-macros#comment1085932_433278) states in their comment, PGF is designed to be usable with TeX so everything is designed for TeX (counts) and thus LaTeX (counters) is *technically* not supported.

You'd have to use

```
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\myisodate}{\c@myjuliandatecounter}
\themyjuliandatecounter
```

but that would need [`@` to be a letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/16595) (which isn't bad per se and depends on your usecase).

If you don't want to use `\c@…` you could use `\csname c@…\endcsname` but that leads us to expansion issues and the same is true for the top-level LaTeX version

```
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\myisodate}{\value{myjuliandatecounter}}
```

---

The reason why `\myjuliandatecommand` fails is because PGFcalendar does at some point

```
\myjuliandatecommand 2458272\relax
```

and that's just nothing (literally, `\myjuliandatecommand` is empty) and the number itself just gets typeset.

It's even worse for `\myweekdaycommand` since that gets used more than once by `\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday`

---

You could do something cheaty like

```
\def\setcounterJulian#1\relax{%
  \setcounter{myjuliandatecounter}{#1}}
%
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\myisodate}{\setcounterJulian}
\themyjuliandatecounter
```

but the same trick won't work for `\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday`.

---

The easiest solution would be to use a TeX count directly, you can even reuse it for `\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}

\newcommand*\myisodate{2018-06-02}
\newcount\PGFcalendarCount

\begin{document} 
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\myisodate}{\PGFcalendarCount}
Julian date: \the\PGFcalendarCount

\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\PGFcalendarCount}{\PGFcalendarCount}
Weekday number: \the\PGFcalendarCount
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the value in a LaTeX counter, define your own wrapper:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\latexpgfcalendardatetojulian}[2]{%
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\count@}%
  \setcounter{#2}{\count@}%
}
\makeatother
```

exploiting the scratch TeX counter `\count@`. If you want to be completely safe, you can add a group

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\latexpgfcalendardatetojulian}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\count@}%
  \setcounter{#2}{\count@}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

because `\setcounter` acts globally.

Let's do the experiment, defining also another wrapper.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfcalendar}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\latexpgfcalendardatetojulian}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\count@}%
  \setcounter{#2}{\count@}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\latexpgfcalendarjuliantoweekday}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{#1}{\count@}%
  \setcounter{#2}{\count@}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{myjuliancounter}
\newcounter{myweekdaycounter}

\begin{document} 

\newcommand{\myisodate}{2018-06-02}

\latexpgfcalendardatetojulian{\myisodate}{myjuliancounter}

The stored value is \themyjuliancounter

\latexpgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\value{myjuliancounter}}{myweekdaycounter}

The stored value is \themyweekdaycounter

\end{document}
```

[image]

With 2022-07-25 (a Monday) we get

[image]